# How to start handler again after calling removeCallbacks or removeCallbacksAndMessages on handler in android

Tags: android, handler

I am working on an android app and have a `Fragment` in which I send an API request each 60 seconds. I am using a `Handler` in this `Fragment` to perform this work in the following manner :

```
// Global Variable in Fragment
private boolean isHandlerStopped = false;

// Create the Handler object (on the main thread by default) Handler handler = new Handler();

// Define the task to be run here
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(!isHandlerStopped){

            // Get the No of New Feeds
            functiontoCall();

            // Repeat this runnable code again every 60 seconds
            handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 60000);
        }
    }
};
handler.post(runnableCode);
```

Now I have some links in this fragment which will open some activity in app and in that activity this fragment will be loaded again.
When I load this fragment in some other activity, I need to remove the callbacks from this handler as I do not want to send request to API in this case. 
So, I have checked the condition and used the below code to stop callBacks.

```
isHandlerStopped = true;
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(runnableCode);
```

and in `onPause` function I have written the below line :

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnableCode);
```

Now when I come back to my fragment again, the handler does not work and If I remove removeCallbacks from onPause function and it works fine.

But I cannot remove `removeCallbacks` method from `onPause` function, how can I start the handler again with this.

Please help me if anyone know how to do this.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `onResume` as well and restart your `Handler` there:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.post(runnableCode);
}
```